# How to read data from MongoDB query result as Json Format in WSO2 Integration Studio Data Service Project?

Tags: mongodb, wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I created mongo database as data service in Integration Studio. I want to call a query from Mongo and read its result as Json. I am trying below method but data is coming as null. I want to read the data returned by Mongo in json format. Can you help with this ?

The Code for Integration Studio Data service xml:

[image]

Data returned by MongoDb Query:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "id": "1234",
      "type": "test"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: What's the MongoDB version you are using?

Comment: İts work from mongo db. It doesnt work send query from wso2 integration studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your output mappings to the following.

```json
{
  "Documents": {
    "Document": [
      {
        "id": "$document._id.id",
        "name": "$document._id.type"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```